# Javascript Next, Prev, Random from an array

Tags: javascript, html

I've created an array where a random word gets chosen when you hit the random word button  but I'm stuck on creating next and previous in order to step through the list.

```
<Script>
        window.onload = myFunction;

        var WordList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
        var Word

        function myFunction() {
        var Word = WordList[Math.floor(Math.random()*WordList.length)];
        document.getElementById("Word").innerHTML = Word;
        }

        function NextWord() {
        var a = WordList.indexOf("Word");

        document.getElementById("Word").innerHTML = a;

    </script>
```

Comment: Is this a typo? You never closed your `NextWord` function. `WordList.indexOf("Word");` returns -1 because "Word" is not in that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your nextWord() function has no closing bracket and you are looking for the index of the string "Word", you rather want to look the indexOf the variable Word, sth like this

```
    function NextWord() {
      var a = WordList.indexOf(Word) ;

      /// check if last entry 
      if((a + 1) == WordList.length) {
         /// reset
         a = 0;
      }else {
         /// increment
         a += 1;
      }
      /// set innerhtml
      document.getElementById("Word").innerHTML = WordList[a];
    }
```

the same you can do for PreviousWord()

Comment: Wow.. Thank you... I used this and it worked (except next when it got to the end got an undefined. I think it went 1 to far past  the array)

Comment: my fault, check if (a + 1) == Wordlist.length

Answer (score 0):

cache the current index of the array

```
var currentIndex = 0, wordList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

function randomWord() {
  currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);
  return wordList[currentIndex];
}

function nextWord() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  currentIndex = Math.min(currentIndex, wordList.length - 1);
  return wordList[currentIndex];
}

function prevWord() {
  currentIndex -= 1;
  currentIndex = Math.max(currentIndex, 0);
  return wordList[currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `Math.min(currentIndex, wordList.length - 1)`